# GitHub Action build .Net Application Run failed

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, github-enterprise

I am new to GitHub Actions, I have a Visual Basic .Net program and I have created it as Repository in GitHub.

After that, I have create a Action to automate build the application when run it. The .yml file content as below:

```html
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

When I try manual run the workflow, it failed with error message below:
Can I know how to install the missing reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v2.0 in order to resolve this, thanks.

[image]

**Question resolved using windows-2019 using @LexLi's solution
I still faced issue in GitHub Enterprise but I will open another question for this. Thanks all**

Comment: You chose the wrong GitHub Actions workflow template (.NET Core) while actually you should choose the .NET Framework one. Delete this workflow and create a new one please.

Comment: Hi @LexLi , thanks for the reply, but in my ACTIONS I not able to find any .NET Framework template, only with .NET template. Or any syntax I need to amend in my .yml file?

Comment: Then you might get hints from posts like https://timheuer.com/blog/building-net-framework-apps-using-github-actions/ In short, use the correct command line tools (`nuget` and `msbuild`). The command `dotnet` is .NET Core exclusive, so you should avoid using it.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I have try to create Action as the posts, however it face the issue when run the flow: 

Run msbuild PIMS.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Mewah
  msbuild PIMS.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Mewah
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
/opt/data-storage/runner/_work/_temp/5929eacd-3ab9-4231-8a2f-52e52d6499df.sh: line 1: msbuild: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

I am using self-hosted is it means my self-hosted runner instance unable to recognize msbuild command?

Comment: To resolve MSBuild path, you can use add a PowerShell script to your folder, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/release.ps1 and then call `powershell -file release.ps1` in your manifest.

Comment: Hi @LexLi , where should i put release.ps1 file in my repo project folder ? just download release.ps1 file and put in repo?

After that how to call in manifest?

Sorry I am not familiar and just new for this, have struggle for few days for this.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, this post is good I manage to build using windows-2019 github hosted runner. Thanks lot for help